# Strange behavior for clearInterval in coffeeScript (not in scope?)

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, setinterval, clearinterval

I'm new to coffeeScript and am having some trouble with what should be a fairly straightforward operation:

```
iGetCalledOnEvents = ->
    _counter

    if condition1
        _counter = setInterval( =>
            if condition2
                # do some stuff
            else
                clearInterval(_counter) # this properly clears the interval
        , 500)
    else
        console.log _counter # this always returns undefined
        clearInterval(_counter) # hence this fails and my world breaks
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Uh, if the `condition1` is not matched then the `_counter` is never assigned to? What else do you expect? Where (and how often) do you call that function?

Comment: Every call to `iGetCalledOnEvents` creates its own scope, with its own `_counter` variable.

Comment: ahh sorry - should have specified, condition1 is always met before it is not. but thank you, the second comment answers this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

_counter variable is defined inside iGetCalledOnEvents function and is deallocated as soon as function returns.

So, you can do:

```
_counter = null
iGetCalledOnEvents = ->
     ...
```